# Keep header width at at least 100% width of content

Tags: css, html, width

I have a header that should stay at least as wide as the below div is or wider. Everything looks fine as the windows is larger than the content but when the window gets smaller so does the top div.

```
#top{

    border:1px solid black;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;

}
#content{
    margin:auto;
    width:1000px;
    height:600px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

<body>
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

Any suggestions?

http://jsfiddle.net/Z242Y/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! None of the provided answers were good but gave me a few ideas, Sorry if I was not specific enough.
http://jsfiddle.net/Z242Y/3/

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is with the fixed width you have on the content where as the top div has a percentage width, so to fix just change the content div to a percentage width that is a little smaller like I did, I set it to 80%

```
#content{
margin:auto;
width:80%;
height:600px;
border:1px solid red;
}
```

Here is your updated [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z242Y/2/)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can wrap your html in a container as such:

```
<div id = "divContainer">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Then, you can give it a fixed width, so that it will decide the width of its contained elements. In this way, both the top and content div will always have the same width.

For that, you will need your CSS to be as such:

```
#divContainer {
    width: 1000px;
}
#top {
    border:1px solid black;
    height:200px;
    width:auto;
}
#content {
    margin:auto;
    height:600px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/G4L4V/

Note: In this approach, the two divs will always have the same width.

In case you want to enforce the 1000px width and still have the content width to be smaller than the top div, then you could make a slight adjustment in the `#content` class as such:

```
#content {
    margin:auto;
    width:90%;
    height:600px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you give an element a width of 100% in CSS, you’re basically making this element’s content area exactly equal to the explicit width of its parent — but only if its parent has an explicit width.

Try setting the width of the #top using javascript.

```
var x = $('#content').width();
$('#top').width(x);
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xerxesnoble/Z242Y/1/)